# Regex - Match a Pattern Before a Character

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently building a toy assembler in c# (going through [The Elements Of Computing Systems](http://www1.idc.ac.il/tecs/) book).

I need to match a very simple pattern, I thought this would be a good time to learn some regex but I'm struggling!

In the following examples I'd just like to match the letters before the '='

M=A

D=M

MD=A

A=D

AD=M

AMD=A

I've come up with the following:

```
([A-Z]{1,3})=
```

However this also matches the '=' which I don't want.

I also tried:

```
([A-Z^\=]{1,3})=
```

But I still have the same problem - it a matches the '=' sign as well.

I'm using [this site](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx) to test my regexes.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You also need to get .Groups[1].Value.ToString() in order to get the appropriate section away from the = sign

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need a [positive lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion):

```
([A-Z]{1,3})(?==)
```

Answer (score 33):

What you want is called a zero-width, lookahead assertion.  You do:

```
(Match this and capture)(?=before this)
```

In your case, this would be:

```
([A-Z^]{1,3})(?==)
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will group everything before the "=" and everything after.

```
([^=]*)=([^=]*)
```

it reads something like this:

match any amount of characters thats not a "=", followed by a "=", then any amount of characters thats not a "=".

Comment: I tried your regex in http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx
It didn't seem to work-  could be something up with the regex engine that site uses? Anyway I've marked an answer now so not to worry. Thanks though.

Comment: The problem with this regular expression might be that, if it's multiline, the second wildcard will match the part after the current equal sign, the newline, and then the characters before the next equal sign.  You'd want to add the delimiter character inside the second pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the equals sign in a non-capturing parans with (?: ... )

```
([ADM]{1,3})(?:=)
```

It's been a bit since I did this chapter of the book but I think that since you need both parts of the expression anyway, I did a split on the = resulting in myArray[0] == M, myArray[1] == A

Comment: The non-capturing parens won't do anything useful.  The equals sign will still be "captured" as part of the overall match, which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Answer (score -2):

I needed to match every character before the '=' so I came up with this

```
.*(?==)=
```

Matches every character before '=' but not "="

Comment: The question was already adequately answered, and I've just matched `==` against your expression, so it does not seem to work. Thanks for participating though.

Comment: Now, when I compared the behaviour to the appropriate answer, I see that this is not what OP wanted.